# plotting in google charts using arrays

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, charts

i have 4 arrays in javascript.I wanted to plot google area charts using these four arrays.My code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
function drawVisualization() {
                var pin1 = new Array();
                '<?php foreach($pin1 as $key => $val){ ?>'
                pin1.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
                '<?php } ?>'
                var pinc_a = new Array();
                '<?php foreach($pinc_a as $key => $val){ ?>'
                pinc_a.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
                '<?php } ?>'
                var pinc_p = new Array();
                '<?php foreach($pinc_p as $key => $val){ ?>'
                pinc_p.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
                '<?php } ?>'
                var pinc_f = new Array();
                '<?php foreach($pinc_f as $key => $val){ ?>'
                pinc_f.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
                '<?php } ?>'
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('number', 'pin1');
                data.addColumn('number', 'pinc_a');
                data.addColumn('number', 'pinc_p');
                data.addColumn('number', 'pinc_f');
                for(var i=0;i<pin.length;i++)
                {
                        data.addRow([pin[i],pinc_a[i],pinc_p[i],pinc_f[i]]);
                }
                var chart=new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
                draw(data, {});
            }
</script>
```

As you can see four arrays are pin1,pic_a,pinc_p,pinc_f.I have taken these      arrays from PHP and used in javascript using push.But the above code is not plotting the chart.where am i going wrong.Please help!

Comment: i used pin1 also in place of pin if you woukd say it is logical error.But its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your columns are type: `'number'`

`data.addColumn('number', 'pin1');`

as such values should be numbers, lose the single quotes...

`pinc_a.push(<?php echo $val; ?>);`